# Fixed Point in the Space of Rational Functions

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, rational-functions

Let $\mathcal R$ be the space of rational functions and $F: \mathcal R \to \mathcal R $ be a function that transforms a rational function into another rational function.

Is there a fixed point theorem that guarantees the existence and uniqueness of $\phi \in \mathcal R$ such that $\phi = F(\phi)$ under conditions on $F$?

Comment: Unless you can suggest some kind of restrictions or conditions on the transformation $F$, this is rather broad. For example, if $F$ is constant then it satisfies what you want.

Comment: Alternately, there are clearly transformations $F$ that do not have any fixed points, for instance letting $F(q(x)) = xq(x)$.

Comment: @JakobHansen $q(x)=0$ is a fixed point of the $F$ you describe.

Comment: Oh, good point. Add x instead, then.